# Active state on click not working (list)

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with the "active" state in CSS. I have a `<ul>` in which there are 4 lists and I want to give these links a different `background-color` (and stay that way!) if they are clicked. The problem is that this won't work...

This is my HTML:

```
<nav id="quick-index-nav">
<ul id="quick-index-list" class="pills slim muted">
<li class="active">
<a id="qindex-popular" title="..." target="right" href="right.php">everything</a>
</li>
<li>
<a id="qindex-today" title="..." target="right" href="right.php?t=tod">today</a>
</li>
<li class="yesterday">
<a id="qindex-yesterday" title="..." target="right" href="right.php?t=yes">tomorrow</a>
</li>
<li>
<a id="qindex-day" title="...." target="right" href="right.php?t=mix">never</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and this is my CSS file:

```
#quick-index-nav{margin-bottom:10px; margin-left: -50px;}
#quick-index-list{margin-bottom:0;*zoom:1;border:0px ridge #d9d9d9}
#quick-index-list:before,#quick-index-list:after{display:table;content:""}
#quick-index-list:after{clear:both}
#quick-index-list li{display:inline-block;float:left;width:25%;margin:0;border:0;-webkit-border-radius:0;-moz-border-radius:0;border-radius:0;border-right:0px ridge #d9d9d9}
#quick-index-list li:nth-child(4n){border-right:0px}
#quick-index-list li:nth-child(n+5){border-top:0px ridge #d9d9d9}
#quick-index-list li>a{padding:0;display:block;font-size:1.0em;text-align:center; font-family: Calibri;}

.pills>li{display:inline-block;margin-bottom:5px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;border:1px solid #d9d9d9}
.pills>li>a{padding:6px 10px;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block}
.pills>li>a:hover{text-decoration:none}
.pills>li:hover{background-color:#d9d9d9;text-decoration:none}
.pills>li.active{background-color:#456695;border-color:#456695}
.pills>li.active>a{color:#fff}
.pills.slim>li>a{padding:3px 5px;font-size:.9em}
.pills.muted>li>a{color:gray}
.pills.muted>li.active>a{color:#fff};
.muted {
    color: gray;
}
```

What is wrong with it?

PS: here is a demo [http://jsfiddle.net/1BJK903/fxTQL/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/1BJK903/fxTQL/1/)

Comment: You haven't defined any style for `a:active`. You have only two rules with `background-color`, and both are visibly working. Which rule do you expect to be in effect for clicked links? ([jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/esezik/1/edit))

Comment: How do you add `.active`class? Javascript? Can you post it?

Comment: I don't use Javascript or jQuery (if there is, it would be welcome) and neither do I use the pseudo element, so I guess that is what is wrong. How do I do that anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to use active pseudo class, than you should have `pills>li:active>a`. Also, I know like it is applied to links only (never used it and this may be wrong), so possibly you will need to change you class like this: `pills>li>a:active`

**Update**

After some tests appeared that this `pills>li:active>a` works in FF, Chrome and IE8+ and does not work in IE7

To do what you need you can enable jquery on your page with this code. Second script tag contains code which will change classes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
   $(".pills li").click(function(){
       $(".pills li").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active"); 
    })​
})
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer...

I want to get the background-color changed of the clicked list. The things you said didn't work. I tried that earlier.

Comment: well ... see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2XYtY/2/). It works for me in chrome

Comment: Uh. If you want it to stay like that after click - that will not work. And there is no such thing in css itself. :active will only be applied while you press mouse button and hold it.

Comment: Oh, I get it... So it won't stay for example red, if it's clicked? Isn't that possible?

Comment: Possible, but only with JS. You must change its class to active, for instance, once it is clicked.

Comment: Yes, that is correct... It has to change it's class to active automatically and that's only possible with JS, obviously. Thanks for the answer. Is there any chance that you have a code which will get me to my goal?

Comment: You could maybe use the :visited pseudo class.

Comment: @BillyMoat - good point, but in few clicks - all links will be highlighted.

Comment: @user1671643 take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxTQL/7/). Well... it is using jquery, but that should not be hard enable it on your page.

Comment: No it won't work... Thank you for your help, but it won't work. It looks like it is going to stay, but it won't... So the background-color is hovered, but it keeps going to the first list again and again, so it is not staying on the clicked element.

Comment: Have you seen a jsfiddle in my previous comment? It works fine, as for me. I think you need to change `li:active` to `li.active` in order to make it work

Comment: Yeah I have seen it, thanks for the effort and it looks like it is working there, but it won't on the mine...

I have a right frame in which items are fetched, so it has to load some stuff. Maybe it has to something with that?

Comment: Ensure that you have `li.active` instead of `li:active` in your css

Comment: That is the case...

That makes it even more odd :S

Comment: cached css? At least I have no more ideas

Comment: Hm. I'm sorry, but it is really hard to understand something there.

Comment: Problem solved by FAngel and FionaG, thank you all! This topic can be closed.